# .ipynb exported to .html wrong skin

Tags: python, html, jupyter-notebook, themes, jupyter-lab

Good morning,

As i wrote, .ipynb exported to .html got wrong background color. I'm working on dark theme and this theme i want to see in exported to .html file.

Any solution i read doesn't help.

*(myenv) PS C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\JUPYTER> jt -r*

*(myenv) PS C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\JUPYTER> jt -t oceans16 -T -N*

doesn't help too.

[I got this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kqtdy.png)

[or this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5u3RC.png)

[and I need like interior of this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Cbg6.png)

would you help me?

Answer (score 3):

Use below commands in anaconda prompt.

I restarted browsers, cleared cache and restarted laptop once before changing themes.

```
jupyter nbconvert project_1.ipynb --to html --HTMLExporter.theme=dark
```

or

```
jupyter nbconvert project_1.ipynb --to html --HTMLExporter.theme=light
```

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:**
Reset the Jupyter theme package in the command prompt with `jt -r`. Then open Jupyter Lab and set the theme for light theme through Settings > JupyterLab Theme. Export the document as an HTML. It should come out with a light background. Close Jupyter Lab. Using Command Prompt set the new jupyter theme with 
`jt -t <theme_name>`. Open Jupyter Lab and set the theme to dark mode through Settings > JupyterLab theme. Export file to HTML again.

It looks like a lot, but its basically just resetting the themes, and then adding the themes again.

If this doesn't work, view the HTML file in a new browser.

Comment: Try uninstalling Jupyter: `python3 -m pip uninstall -y jupyter jupyter_core jupyter-client jupyter-console notebook qtconsole nbconvert nbformat`

Comment: and uninstall JupyterTheme: `pip uninstall jupyterthemes`

Comment: And then reinstall both packages

Comment: If that doesn't help, try viewing the HTML file in a new browser.

Comment: I got it! There is problem with browser type. At least Yandex Browser and Microsoft Edge can't open this .html correctly but Internet Explorer do all job. Haha, thank you! Is it possible to upgrade/repair this .html code to read it file in newer browser correctly?

Comment: Great to hear! What OS are you using, and what is your processor?

Comment: I said too fast. It just look as ok but it isn't. Here you are:  [MS Edge](https://icecube-eu-285.icedrive.io/thumbnail?p=tUXX3rXeOdStA32dIKVROMNgf%2F1Uqyoy7OFGAQaksYxgYAu1TXqfO4L6RpzB8lnSIPGaosNm%2FJ9gq2GizXimxhTmJRcn%2FtWCLAQUuikgNwGwKMmupJFivHPHoVCLyVGV&w=1280&h=1280&m=cropped) and [Internet Explorer](https://icecube-eu-283.icedrive.io/thumbnail?p=xpCqaxduY0KvkDJCep6o8GrzrWthEaYxp6S%2FZUnQn81wHVpeCh4XntBEBzh4i0t7fd6C3D4VRR%2Bj8%2F1SwAHa5rHxZrrSksx0uk%2BpBOaJbJ0X9Skqp2FprVkS8e%2FfKhni&w=1280&h=1280&m=cropped). I didn't try first way yet.

Comment: When you export the file, in which browser was Jupyter Lab?

Comment: Also, try viewing the file in Google Chrome or Firefox